# How to ask GPS Permission first for 'While Using', then for 'Always'? (2 Steps)

Tags: ios, geolocation

I'm designing an app that works with **Check-Ins**.

GPS Permission when using the app is a **must**. But there's an **optional feature** for Automatic Check In using Geofencing, which needs the 'Always' gps permission.

I would like to ask for regular 'While Using' permissions at first. And then, **only when a user wants** Automatic Check In, ask for 'Always' permissions.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: please add these 3 keys in your project's .plist file]

-->First add these three keys to the info.plist file or you can add as per your requirement either 1st and 2nd key or 1st and 3rd key.

-->In "myclass.h" set up delegate as "CLLocationManagerDelegate" and it will ask you for the GPS while first time while using and the below code to the "myclass.m" file

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];   //For while use the app
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]; // For always usage of GPS 
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude] );
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude] );

  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
```

}

--Note: If you want always use of GPS permission then no needs to be ask for while using in permission.

[image]

--> if you add both permission then you will get this kind of options in your device setting application and user can also set when they want to use which permissions. One permission will not show both in the device setting.

device settings --> My App --> Allow my app to access (select location) --> Location access permision